# Speed-related tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

We have both [speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speed):

> Questions about optimizing your computer to take up less boot time,
>   application launch time, download time, etc.

and [internet-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-speed).

I think we can either merge them, or make [speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speed) more specific. [performance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance) is used a lot with [speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speed), too.

There's also [cpu-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu-speed), [clockspeed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clockspeed), [speedtest](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speedtest) (can be merged with [internet-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-speed)) and [typing-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/typing-speed) (can be merged with [typing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/typing)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree partially.  I believe that it makes more sense to merge [speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speed) into [performance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance), as they are at a comparable level of generality.  I do not agree that [speedtest](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speedtest) should be merged with [internet-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-speed); if anything, [speedtest](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speedtest) is more closely clustered with [performance-tuning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning) and [performance-comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance-comparison), as it could refer to tests involving [cpu-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu-speed) and [clockspeed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clockspeed).

Merging [typing-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/typing-speed) with [typing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/typing) seems reasonable.

---

<kidding>While we’re at it, let’s add [disk-speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-speed).</kidding>